# Help finding equation for my calculus class

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

I mentioned in my class that an equation could describe a curve like this:

[image]

I drew the curve so that the crossing point was at the origin $(0,0)$, and the loop was in the first quadrant. Can you give an equation that would describe a curve like this?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the [Folium of Descartes](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Curves/Foliumd.html)

Comment: @pjs36 yes! thanks!

Comment: Could also be a part of any of several [trisectrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisectrix) flavors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the "Folium of Descartes". The equation is 
$$x^3+y^3-3axy=0.$$
In polar coordinates is
$$r=\frac{3a\sin\theta\cos\theta}{\sin^3\theta+\cos^3\theta}.$$

Comment: yes! that's it!